# Problem changing resolution using xrandr: BadMatch

Tags: 10.04, configuration, xrandr

I tried to change the resolution using the following commands (found [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution)):

Use `xrandr` to check the current configuration and available modes:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 64 x 64, current 800 x 600, maximum 32000 x 32000
VBOX1 connected 800x600+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   800x600        60.0*+
   640x480        59.9
```

Use `cvt` to get the proper modeline for 1280x800:

```
$ cvt 1280 800
# 1280x800 59.81 Hz (CVT 1.02MA) hsync: 49.70 kHz; pclk: 83.50 MHz
Modeline "1280x800_60.00"   83.50  1280 1352 1480 1680  800 803 809 831 -hsync +vsync
```

Create the new mode using `xrandr --newmode`:

```
$ xrandr --newmode "1280x800_60.00"   83.50  1280 1352 1480 1680  800 803 809 831 -hsync +vsync
```

Use `xrandr` again to check that the mode was created successfully:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 64 x 64, current 800 x 600, maximum 32000 x 32000
VBOX1 connected 800x600+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   800x600        60.0*+
   640x480        59.9  
  1280x800_60.00 (0x11a)   83.0MHz
        h: width  1280 start 1352 end 1480 total 1680 skew    0 clock   49.4KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  831           clock   59.5Hz
```

However, when I try to add the new mode to the display with `xrandr --addmode` I get the following error:

```
$ xrandr --addmode VBOX1 1280x800_60.00
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  150 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  18
  Current serial number in output stream:  19
```

Of course, if I try to set the new resolution for my current display it fails (the mode isn't associated to te display):

```
$ xrandr --output VBOX1 --mode 1280x800_60.00
xrandr: cannot find mode 1280x800_60.00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that you're trying within VirtualBox. If it's the case, just install VirtualBox Guest Addition, you can get any resolution (by resizing the VirtualBox window)

Comment: Thanks, I had installed the Gust Additions but Ubuntu still only showed me 800x600 and 640x480. I thought that Ubuntu would show me bigger resolutions options and resize the vbox window according to the resolution selected.... and not the other way arround: resizing the vbox window would allow me to select bigger resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
sudo xrandr --output VBOX1 --scale 1.5x1.5
```

you can change the 1.5x1.5 per another scale factor